# Dirty Reading in hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Dirty Read: The definition states that

> dirty reading occurs when a transaction reads data from a row that has been modified by another transaction but not yet committed.

Assuming the definition is correct, I am unable to fathom any such situation.

Due to the principle of Isolation, the transaction A can not see the uncommitted data of the row that has been modified by transaction B. If transaction B has simply not committed, how transaction A can see it in the first place? It is only possible when both operations are performed under same transaction.

Can someone please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: It refers to: processA selects the old data after the time processB writes the data (updates a row) and before the time processB executes a commit.  Oracle provides for atomic transactions to get around this issue.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dirty", or uncommitted reads (UR) are a way to allow non-blocking reads. Reading uncommitted data is not possible in an Oracle database due to the multi-version concurrency control employed by Oracle; instead of trying to read other transactions' data each transaction gets its own snapshot of data as they existed (committed) at the start of the transaction. As a result all reads are essentially non-blocking.

In databases that use lock-based concurrency control, e.g DB2, uncommitted reads are possible. A transaction using the UR isolation level ignores locks placed by other transactions, and thus it is able to access rows that have been modified but not yet committed.

Hibernate, being an abstraction layer on top of a database, offers the UR isolation level support for databases that have the capability.